# Selenium + Python - how to get the response from the site after uploading an image

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload images to Microsoft's http://how-old.net/ API to compare with our age and gender classification algorithm [1].

I've managed to upload images to the site, but I can't figure out how to get the response (i.e. age and gender classifications).

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://how-old.net/")
file_input=driver.find_element_by_id("uploadBtn")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {visibility: 'visible'};", file_input)
a = file_input.send_keys("D:\\AdienceFaces\\aligned\\7153718@N04\\landmark_aligned_face.2282.11597935265_29bcdfa4a5_o.jpg")
```

Is there any way to get the prediction?

Thanks in advance!
Gil

[1] Levi, Gil, and Tal Hassner. "Age and Gender Classification using Convolutional Neural Networks."

EDIT: Added wait commands and other code lines, still returns None:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time



driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://how-old.net/")

time.sleep(60)

file_input=driver.find_element_by_id("uploadBtn")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {visibility: 'visible'};", file_input)
file_input.send_keys("D:\\AdienceFaces\\aligned\\7153718@N04\\landmark_aligned_face.2282.11598166203_c70bb34c80_o.jpg")

time.sleep(60)

ages = driver.execute_script("function get_ages() { arr=[]; $('#faces .tooltip-inner div').each(function () { arr.push($(this).text()); }); return arr;}; get_ages();")
print ages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ages = driver.execute_script("function get_ages() { arr=[]; $('#faces .tooltip-inner div').each(function () { arr.push($(this).text()); }); return arr;}; return get_ages()")
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, but I get that ages is None (but the image was classified).

Comment: You probably need to wait for the page to be fully loaded before running that script. I tested it direcly on the website, it returns an array of names.

Comment: Thanks @Maresh, but I still get "None" even after waiting and adding "wait" commands. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Ok, my bad I forgot the 'return'. Edited answer